# upload file on supabase using appsmith corrupt image

Tags: javascript, supabase, supabase-js, appsmith

I'm trying to upload an image on supabase storage with appsmith and the file picker option.
It work but my file is corrupt and i don't know why.

```
export default {
function: async () => {
    const sup = JSObject1.client //is the supabase-js client
    const { data, error } = await sup
    .storage
    .from('image')
    .upload(FilePicker1.files[0].name, FilePicker1.files[0].data, {contentType: "image/png"})
    console.log(error)
    console.log(data)
},
```

[upload with appsmith](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l78iB.png)

i uploaded a test image with the supabase drag and drop tool to compare the size of the image i want to upload

[upload with supabase drag and drop tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcXTb.png)

you see the size is fatter on the image post with appsmith

Any solution ?

I check binary on appsmith filepicker but same problem

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a result after few hours.

1. You need to change the datatype of **filepicker** to **Base64**
2. remove the uri because the base64 data begin by 'data:contentType:base64,'
   with for example `data.split('base64,')[1]`
3. you need a fonction to decode base64, appsmith support lib but i find a simple function for that.

   Put that's code in an jsobject

```
base64ToArrayBuffer : (base64) => {
 var binaryString = atob(base64);
 var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryString.length);
 for (var i = 0; i < binaryString.length; i++) {
     bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
 }
 return bytes.buffer;
 }
```

4. decode and send (don't forget the contenttype option)

```
const { data, error } = await sup
        .storage
        .from('image')
        .upload(appsmith.store.image.name, JSObject1.base64ToArrayBuffer(base64), {contentType: "image/png"})
        console.log(error)
        console.log(data)
```